# How do i convert this rotation method using Arrays to Use Lists Instead?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a method that uses arrays to rotate values while keeping the value occupying the final index in the same position.

How do I use Lists to do the same thing?

```
        /*
     * Maintains the value and index of the last value in the array, while rotating the remaining values
     */
    private static Team[] rotateTeams(Team[] teamsArray)
    {
        // capture last value in array 
        Team lastPosition = teamsArray[teamsArray.Length - 1];
        // create a smaller array to hold remaining values
        Team[] smallerTeamArray = new Team[teamsArray.Length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < smallerTeamArray.Length; i++)
        {
            smallerTeamArray[i] = teamsArray[i];
        }
        // create a temporary smaller array to rotate values
        Team[] tempTeamsArray = new Team[smallerTeamArray.Length];
        // choose how many positions to rotate
        int rotate = 1;
        // populate temp array with rotated values
        for (int i = 0; i < smallerTeamArray.Length; i++)
        {
            tempTeamsArray[i] = smallerTeamArray[(i + rotate) % smallerTeamArray.Length];
        }
        // repopulate larger array with values and positions from smaller temp array
        for (int i = 0; i < teamsArray.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            teamsArray[i] = tempTeamsArray[i];
        }
        // add captured last value from above to final position in array
        teamsArray[teamsArray.Length - 1] = lastPosition;
        return teamsArray;
    }
```

Comment: By changing the method declaration so it takes a list and changing `Length` to `Count`?

Answer (score 1):

you should have changes like this

```
private static List<Team> rotateTeams(List<Team> teamsArray)
        {
            // capture last value in array 
            Team lastPosition = teamsArray[teamsArray.Count - 1];
            // create a smaller array to hold remaining values
            List<Team> smallerTeamArray = new List<Team>();
            for (int i = 0; i < smallerTeamArray.Count; i++)
            {
                smallerTeamArray[i] = teamsArray[i];
            }
            // create a temporary smaller array to rotate values
            List<Team> tempTeamsArray = new List<Team>();
            // choose how many positions to rotate
            int rotate = 1;
            // populate temp array with rotated values
            for (int i = 0; i < smallerTeamArray.Count; i++)
            {
                tempTeamsArray[i] = smallerTeamArray[(i + rotate) % smallerTeamArray.Count];
            }
            // repopulate larger array with values and positions from smaller temp array
            for (int i = 0; i < teamsArray.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                teamsArray[i] = tempTeamsArray[i];
            }
            // add captured last value from above to final position in array
            teamsArray[teamsArray.Count - 1] = lastPosition;
            return teamsArray;
        }
```

Comment: Seriously? You really think the comment to the question isn‘t enough?

Comment: Loop for smallerTeamArray i = 0 , count = 0 , rest seems ok, will work on creating the smaller list